QGIS all features disappear when any are selected
QGIS 3.34.9
I have a layer of point features derived from an Excel spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet Layers plugin. If I select any features using any of the map selection tools all of the features disappear from the map. The same happens if I select features in the Attribute table.

I have never used the Spreadsheet Layers plugin. No idea if that is the source of your issue. There is a way to create a point feature using the native Create points layer from table. If that doesn't solve if, maybe it's a filter issue.
